# What is causing this [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor error while using os.write

Tags: python, file-io

```
import os

# Open the file in write-only mode
g = os.open("d:\Coding\Python\OS module practise.txt", os.O_WRONLY)
os.write(g, b"Hi")
```

I ran this code and I am getting the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "d:\Coding\Python\Practice
> files\Practice\day 12\practice4.py", line 7, in 
> os.write(g, b"HI") OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

I don't understand what is the problem?

I tried adding "Hi" to the txt file but it threw an error.

Comment: Did you try printing `g` to see if `os.open()` succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

`\` is a special character in strings. For example, `\n` means newline, `\t` means TAB. If you want to include an actual \ character in a string, you will need to "escape" the `\` with an extra `\`. Try: `"d:\\Coding\\Python\\OS module practise.txt"`

I will also note that there is an easier way to append to a file!

```
filename = "d:\\Coding\\Python\\OS module practise.txt"
with open(filename, 'a+') as file:
    current_text = file.read()
    new_text = current_text + "Hi!"
    file.write(new_text)
```

Comment: Raw strings or using `/` are easier.

Comment: sub·jec·tive
adjective: subjective

    1.
    based on or influenced by personal feelings, tastes, or opinions.
    "his views are highly subjective"

Comment: Less error-prone, IMHO. The more things you have to add, the more likely you are to miss one.

Comment: And it looks just like a pathname the way you use it in other contexts. Being different is confusing.

Comment: OP forgot to close their file as well. Using a `with` context manager simplifies things.

Comment: I assumed the OP is deliberately playing with the `os` functions, so not interested in the python built-in way. `os.open()` doesn't implement a context manager, since it just returns an int.